# Error in secure load of data source. An error occurred while decrypting data

Tags: encryption, wso2, datasource, esb

I know a similar question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846614/external-datasources-not-working-with-secured-wso2-dss-3-2-2) but since given answer don't help me and my problem is kinda different I'm asking a new question.

I create data sources through `admin panel -> Configure -> Datasources` and it works fine. But if I restart server all created *Datasources* gonna missing from datasources list.

When I run *ESB* server I can see through logs that those datasources could not be loaded properly since ESB server is unable to decrypt sensitive data which it encrypted earlier:

> DataSourceRepository Error in updating data source [remove:false] at path '/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/myDatasource
>
> Error in updating data source 'myDatasource' from registry
>   [remove:false]: Error in secure load of data source
>
> meta info: An error occurred while decrypting data

Although *myDatasource* is missing from datasources list I can still see it in registry through `admin panel -> Registry -> /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/myDatasource`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. This seems to be some error introduced in 6.4.0.
6.3.0 does not exhibit this behaviour.

As a workaround, if you define the datasources in **/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml** then the datasources load correctly at server startup. However this is not ideal solution as they cannot then be edited through the web console.

Alternatively you can download the registry entry , edit the password element to remove 'Encrypted=true' and change the password to be unencrypted. Then upload the edited file as a new registry entry alongside the old.

Both these methods are not feasible for production though as they leave the passwords unencrypted.

Out of interest are you running this on Windows? I discovered also on EI 6.4.0 that the Ciphertool utility will not run due to a malformed path. I suspect this might be related, but I cannot find where the malformed path is coming from it seems to be repeating the {carbon.home} element within the path :

```
    C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0\bin>ciphertool
Using CARBON_HOME:   C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\jdk\jdk1.8.0_192
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 51: C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0\C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0\/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.getConfigFilePath(Utils.java:98)
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.setSystemProperties(Utils.java:289)
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.initialize(CipherTool.java:93)
        at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.main(CipherTool.java:52)
```

Comment: Hi will, I hope you are well. I were aware of `/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml` and I used it as a temporary solution for now. I am running this on windows. Is it possible malformed path be space character in address of CARBON_HOME or JAVA_HOME?

Comment: This has been logged as a known issue within 6.4.0 Here https://github.com/wso2/cipher-tool/issues/36